# Windows 8 Storage Spaces Hard Drives Spinning Up

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, storage-spaces

I'm having issues with my Storage Space in Windows 8.

I've got a space set up as a two-way mirror, with about 5 non-equal sized drives in it.

For the most part, it works just fine. I use it mainly for storage of files, so access speeds isn't hugely important.

However every now and then (maybe once an hour, when not used frequently), it will take about 30 seconds for the storage space to respond to any access attempt. It sounds like the hard drives are spinning up, and that's what it's waiting for, these hard drives to turn on again. Once everything gets all up and running, it works fine.

So, how do I best resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

If this issue is still prevalent (seeing as the question is from 2013), I suggest the following:

1. Update your Windows. Storage Spaces came a long way since and I would be surprised if you are still successfully using your Windows 8 machine without having lost any data. Described behavior may genuinely be a bug in old version of Storage Spaces.
2. **Check your BIOS.** Some motherboards have setting that has a title something along the lines of "Use aggressive power management" in relation to peripherals, or SATA storage. Disable this option.

Comment: Both these suggestions come from actual experience with Storage Spaces, which have bugs in them and Microsoft is fixing them continuously. BIOS options are also at play with hardware related questions. If someone is downvoting this, please be so kind to at least say why.